# Howe to transond the output as 2 dimension

Tags: sql, pivot, transpose

My data-table is this:

| Weektype | Weekday | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0800-1400 |
| 1 | 2 | 0900-1500 |
| 1 | 3 | 0800-1500 |
| 1 | 4 | 0800-1530 |
| 6 | 5 | 0800-1300 |
| 7 | 5 | 0900-1400 |

The weekday represent mon to fri.

I want the output to be like this:

| Weektype | Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0800-1400 | 0900-1500 | 0800-1500 | 0800-1530 |  |
| 6 |  |  |  |  | 0800-1300 |
| 7 |  |  |  |  | 0900-1400 |

---

**Build Example table:**

```
Create table #tbl1 (Weektype INT, Weekday varchar(3),Time varchar(20))

Insert into #tbl1 (Weektype,Weekday,Time)
values (1,'1','0800-1400'),(1,'2','0900-1500'),(1,'3','0800-1500'),(1,'4','0800-1530'),(6,'5','0800-1300'),(7,'5','0900-1400')
```

**My query**

```
Select Distinct 
org.Weektype
,day1.Time as Monday
,day2.Time as Tuesday
,day3.Time as Wednesday
,day4.Time as Thursday
,day5.Time as Fri

from #tbl1 org

cross join #tbl1 Week on Week.Weektype = org.Weektype 
left join #tbl1 day1 on day1.Weekday = Week.Weekday AND Week.Weekday = 1
Left join #tbl1 day2 on day2.Weekday = Week.Weekday AND Week.Weekday = 2
Left join #tbl1 day3 on day3.Weekday = Week.Weekday AND Week.Weekday = 3
Left join #tbl1 day4 on day4.Weekday = Week.Weekday AND Week.Weekday = 4
Left join #tbl1 day5 on day5.Weekday = Week.Weekday AND Week.Weekday = 5

group by org.Weektype
```

Cleaning up

`Drop table #tbl1`

---

**My result:**

| Weektype | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Fri |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 0800-1530 | NULL |
| 1 | NULL | NULL | 0800-1500 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | NULL | 0900-1500 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 0800-1400 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 6 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 0800-1300 |
| 6 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 0900-1400 |
| 7 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 0800-1300 |
| 7 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 0900-1400 |

Comment: I wonder why you're trying to do this in a query and not in the frontend / GUI? That's where this _should_ be handled.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that you cannot have duplicate `(weektype, weekday)` pairs?

Comment: @RobIII: This is a simplified example from a large base, where we have to design our own reports, to easely check that everybody have registered from - to time.

Comment: @SalmanA: It is guarantieed that is no duplicate (weektype, weekday).

Comment: I posted an answer, uses conditional aggregation.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: @Helge Still, reports should be done in the UI/Application layer, not in the database layer. This is a 'report problem', not a database problem. But maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregate function like MAX

```
Select 
org.Weektype
,MAX(day1.Time) as Monday
,MAX(day2.Time) as Tuesday
,MAX(day3.Time) as Wednesday
,MAX(day4.Time) as Thursday
,MAX(day5.Time) as Fri

from #tbl1 org

cross join #tbl1 Week on Week.Weektype = org.Weektype 
left join #tbl1 day1 on day1.Weekday = Week.Weekday AND Week.Weekday = 1
Left join #tbl1 day2 on day2.Weekday = Week.Weekday AND Week.Weekday = 2
Left join #tbl1 day3 on day3.Weekday = Week.Weekday AND Week.Weekday = 3
Left join #tbl1 day4 on day4.Weekday = Week.Weekday AND Week.Weekday = 4
Left join #tbl1 day5 on day5.Weekday = Week.Weekday AND Week.Weekday = 5

group by org.Weektype
```

But ou can simpilf pou approach

```
Select 
org.Weektype
,MAX(CASE WHEN org.Weekday = 1 THEN org.Time ELSe NULL END ) as Monday
,MAX(CASE WHEN org.Weekday = 2 THEN org.Time ELSe NULL END ) as Tuesday
,MAX(CASE WHEN org.Weekday = 3 THEN org.Time ELSe NULL END ) as Wednesday
,MAX(CASE WHEN org.Weekday = 4 THEN org.Time ELSe NULL END ) as Thursday
,MAX(CASE WHEN org.Weekday = 5 THEN org.Time ELSe NULL END ) as Frida

from #tbl1 org
group by org.Weektype
```

| Weektype | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Frida |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0800-1400 | 0900-1500 | 0800-1500 | 0800-1530 | *null* |
| 6 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 0800-1300 |
| 7 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 0900-1400 |

```
SELECT Weektype,   
  [1] as Monday, [2] as Tuesday, [3] as Wednesday, [4] as Thursday, [5]  as Frida
FROM  
    #tbl1
PIVOT  
(  
  MAX(Time)  
  FOR Weekday IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])  
) AS PivotTable;
```

| Weektype | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Frida |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0800-1400 | 0900-1500 | 0800-1500 | 0800-1530 | *null* |
| 6 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 0800-1300 |
| 7 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | 0900-1400 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fuU11w5X)

Comment: This was helpful, but I am not allowed to use  "on Week.Weektype = org.Weektype" in the cross join. An the resault is same time in week 6 an 7 at Friday.

Comment: Cross Join makes a cartasian product so a on clause makes no sense. I will see later fo a better approach  you are using SQL server I guess?

Comment: @Helge there are two approaches to our problem see the changed answer